# How to specify the web server location?

Tags: php, apache-flex, webserver, flash-builder

I am using flash builder to build an application. I've been using a wamp server to test on, but now I need to redirect it to a remote server. I have a domain name that is linked up to 000webhost server and is working fine, so that is the root URL. The web root will be \public_html\prototype. But when I put them both in, flash builder says that the web root doesn't exist (but they are directories on the server) and my URL works fine when I put it into the browser so I can't see where the issue is? Anyone know what I'm missing? Is the web root not directories on the server?

So currently the web root I put is: \public_html\prototype

And the root URL is:

```
http://mel********dt.com (it is connected to 000webhost and works fine)
```

The error message I get with this is: The selected web root folder does not exist (It does on the server)

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to do is to change the endpoint property of the serviceControl.
Go to your service package: If you have employees service, then you should look for a file called Super_EployeesService.as. In this file you have to change this endpoint to the new url, or where exactly are the service located and the gateway.php file.

```
_serviceControl.endpoint = "http://mel********dt.com/.../.../gateway.php";
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Because it's still doing the same thing. Is there anything else that needs to be changed that I'm missing?

Comment: This points your application to the gateway.php file on the remote server. After that the gateway.php points to the services that you need to access.